# using reduce inside a python map function

Tags: python, python-2.7, mapreduce, python-multiprocessing

I have this case where I have a list of lists of lists, and I need to apply a reduce on each of the sub lists of the first list.
The reduce function requires 2 parameters, but that 2nd parameter (the list of lists I want to apply the reduce on), is supposed to be from the main list I pass to the map function
Consider the snippet below.

```
reducedLists = map(reduce(lambda first, second : map(operator.add, first,second), XXX), listsToReduce)
```

I need to know what should be passed in place of `XXX` above.

Here `listsToReduce` is a list of lists of lists like `[[[1,2,3], [3,2,1]],[[1,3,5],[5,3,1]]]`.

I want the final output of the above map and reduce to be 2 lists
`[[4,4,4],[6,6,6]]` which is a pairwise sum of the inner list of list passed to the map.
I could not figure how I can model the map and reduce to pass proper parameters to the reduce function.

My ultimate objective is to use `Pool.map` from the `multiprocessing` package to perform the reduce operations on multiple cores. Any inputs on restructuring the code with this in mind are much appreciated.

Comment: I understand you wish to use `map`, but do you need to use `reduce`? I can see how this could be done with, say `zip` instead.

Comment: reduce seems to take multiple lists and reduce it to one value. I don't think you can do what you want with reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd perform that pairwise summing operation this way:

```
listsToReduce = [[[1,2,3], [3,2,1]], [[1,3,5], [5,3,1]]]
reducedLists = [list(map(sum, zip(*lst))) for lst in listsToReduce]
print(reducedLists)
```

**output**

```
[[4, 4, 4], [6, 6, 6]]
```

In Python 2, `map` returns a list, so you could do

```
[map(sum, zip(*lst)) for lst in listsToReduce]
```

but I strongly recommend the use of Python 3 for all new code, since Python 2 reaches its official End of Life in 2020.

---

Here's another way to do it in Python 2, but it's less efficient due to the use of the `lambda` function instead of `sum`.

```
from operator import add

reducedLists = map(lambda t: map(add, *t), listsToReduce)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question using the desired approach:

```py
from functools import partial, reduce
import operator

listsToReduce = [[[1,2,3], [3,2,1]],[[1,3,5],[5,3,1]]]

f = partial(reduce, lambda first, second : list(map(operator.add, first,second)))
map(f, listsToReduce)
```